# The method .map is not defined for type FUTURE

Tags: flutter, rest, dart, dropdown

I am trying to pull a list of products from an REST api to show up in a dropdown. Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:gateway_device/backend/api/api_services.dart';
import 'package:gateway_device/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import 'package:gateway_device/models/products_list_model.dart';
import 'package:gateway_device/routes/route_helper.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class EditDevicePortWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String deviceId;
  final String portId;
  final String publicId;
  final String label;

  const EditDevicePortWidget(
      {Key? key,
      required this.deviceId,
      required this.portId,
      required this.publicId,
      required this.label})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EditDevicePortWidget> createState() =>
      _EditDevicePortWidgetState(deviceId, portId, publicId, label);
}

class _EditDevicePortWidgetState extends State<EditDevicePortWidget> {
  final String deviceId;
  final String portId;
  final String publicId;
  final String label;
  late String dropDownValueSelected = '';
  Future<List<TankProduct>> dropDownProduct = ApiService().getAllProducts();
  late TextEditingController textController1 = TextEditingController();
  late TextEditingController textController2 = TextEditingController();
  late TextEditingController textController3 = TextEditingController();
  late TextEditingController textController4 = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    String dropDownValueSelected = '';
    textController1.text = '';
    textController2.text = '';
    textController3.text = '';
    textController4.text = '';
  }

  _EditDevicePortWidgetState(
      this.deviceId, this.portId, this.publicId, this.label);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          publicId + ' - ' + label,
          style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodyText1.override(
                fontFamily: 'Heebo',
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
            // borderRadius: 30,
            // borderWidth: 1,
            iconSize: 40,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.close,
              color: Colors.black,
              size: 30,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Get.offNamed(RouteHelper.getPortProfile(
                  deviceId, portId, publicId, label));
            },
          ),
        ],
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.h * 1,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 10, 0, 0),
                            child: Text(
                              'Product:',
                              style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                  .bodyText1
                                  .override(
                                    fontFamily: 'Heebo',
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: [
                          DropdownButton<String>(
                              value: dropDownValueSelected,
                              items: dropDownProduct.map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                        value: item,
                                        child: Text(item,
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                                      ))
                                  .toList(),
                              onChanged: (item) => setState(() {
                                    dropDownValueSelected = item!;
                                  }))
                        ],
                      ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'Future'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'map'.

The error is from line 121.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: dropDownProduct is a Future, you need to await the return of this future before using .map on the result.

Comment: Can you please show me where I would use await?

Answer (score 1):

As VincentDR commented, `dropDownProduct` is a Future and it should be awaited. There are multiple ways to achieve this, some more better or prettier than others... I would suggest to remove this line:
`Future<List<TankProduct>> dropDownProduct = ApiService().getAllProducts();`
Since you should not be invoking an async method and/or communicating with an API in your view. I suggest you investigate state handling and separating your app into layers.

But if you want a quick and functional solution, you can use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to await for the future to complete, it should be something like this:

```
  FutureBuilder(
    future: ApiService().getAllProducts(),
    builder(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot){
        // Validate if snapshot is loading or if there is an error
        if(snapshot.hasError){
          // Give feedback to the user about error
        } else if(!snapshot.hasData){
          // Give feedback to the user about loading in progress
        } else {
         return Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              DropdownButton<String>(
                  value: dropDownValueSelected,
                  items: dropDownProduct.map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: item,
                            child: Text(item,
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                          ))
                      .toList(),
                  onChanged: (item) => setState(() {
                        dropDownValueSelected = item!;
                      }))
            ],
          );
        }
    }
  );
```

Comment: The example that you showed using future builder is something I am aware of and use it in my code in other places. However considering I have multiple dropdowns that will pull data from the api, i cant use this. The reason I set it up the way I did with the variable being set to call the function I built in ApiServices, was because I thought it would return the list.

Comment: Also, I did try to use your example and it does not like the <String> after AsyncSnapshot.  It breaks the rest of the code.

Comment: If you plan to use the very same method from the ApiServices, you can move the `FutureBuilder` up in the widget tree and access it from those multiple dropdowns (take into account that this will rebuild all its children every time the future builder returns a new value)
If you are planning to invoke different methods from the ApiServices, maybe it would be better to create a private widget that receives a future function, and this private widget should have its own `FutureBuilder` and it should build the dropdown, this way you can use the very same code to build different dropdowns.

Comment: Regarding the <String> issue, it is probably happening because your method returns a List< TankProduct>, sorry about that, I haven't used `FutureBuilder` in a while.

Comment: But I cant do one Future Builder for multiple API calls which I have 3 different dropdowns that will be pulling data from an api

Comment: That's why I've suggested having a private widget that receives a custom function, builds a dropdown, and fetches data depending on the function received. This will work if you are going to use different functions from the `ApiServices`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249053/discussion-between-mackina-and-fabian-bardecio).

Answer (score 0):

`ApiService().getAllProducts()` returns a `Future` so you need to add `await` before `ApiService().getAllProducts()` to get `List<TankProduct>` that you can later use to show a dropdown.

```
List<TankProduct> dropDownProduct = [];

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
     setState((){
         dropDownProduct = await ApiService().getAllProducts();
     });
    }
}
```

Now you can use the `dropDownProduct` list to show dropdown inside the `DropdownButton` widget.

```
DropdownButton<String>(
     value: dropDownValueSelected,
     items: dropDownProduct.map((item) {
              // ...
    })
```

Comment: Now in the dropdownButton inside items, I am using DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: item, child: Text(item)  However, I am getting the error:

The argument type 'TankProduct' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String?'.

Comment: This is because you are trying to assign a `TankProduct` to a `Text` that expects a `String`. You have to choose what you want to display in the `Text` widget, for example, if you wanted to display the `TankProduct` name, you should do it like this:
DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: item, child: Text(item.name)